# How can I use ?? to combine these two lines into one?

Tags: c#

I would like to get the two **attribute-assignment** lines below into one line since I'm going to build them into an application where they will be numerous.

**Is there a way to express those two lines in one line of elegantly constructed C#, perhaps with a ?? operator like this?**

```
string nnn = xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display").Value ?? "";
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestNoAttribute
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XElement xml = new XElement(
                new XElement("employee",
                    new XAttribute("id", "23"),
                    new XElement("firstName", new XAttribute("display", "true"), "Jim"),
                    new XElement("lastName", "Smith")));

            //is there any way to use ?? to combine this to one line?
            XAttribute attribute = xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display");
            string lastNameDisplay = attribute == null ? "NONE" : attribute.Value;

            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            Console.WriteLine(lastNameDisplay);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can!

Just do this:

```
string lastNameDisplay = (string)xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display") ?? "NONE";
```

Comment: yes, that was what I was looking for, and still quite readable I think as long as you know what the ?? does, thanks!

Comment: ?? is before explicit casts in precedence?

Comment: I was in a meeting or I would have replied earlier. The `XAttribute` will cast to a null string, which is then coalesced and replaced with "NONE".

Comment: This is also very useful for other attribute types that may not exist (like a nullable int): `int demoInt = (int?)xml.Element("element").Attribute("attribute") ?? 12;`

Comment: As someone voted this answer down, it would be great to be given an explanation for it - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Sure, but it's awful, not elegant:

```
string lastNameDisplay = xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display") == null ? "NONE" : xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display").Value;
```

If you're willing, you could write an extension method:

```
public static string GetValue(this XAttribute attribute)
{
    if (attribute == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return attribute.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = attribute.GetValue();
```

Comment: Extension method is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a small helper function which takes an XElement and returns the lastNameDisplay string?

Comment: Readable code is far more valuable than compact code. +1 for being the only answer to sacrifice neither.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
string lastNameDisplay = (xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display") ?? new XAttribute("display", "NONE")).Value;
```

Comment: This is for the "null 'this' references in extension methods should throw NRE" crowd.

Comment: This *does* answer the question, but I'm not sure I'd want to be creating extra objects when I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. What you're looking for is a null guard (I think that's what it's called), which c# does not have. It would only call the guarded property if the preceding object is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The closest you'll get is with an extension method like the following:

```
public static string ValueOrDefault(this XAttribute attribute, string Default)
{
    if(attribute == null)
        return Default;
    else
        return attribute.Value;
}
```

Then you can shorten your two lines into:

```
string lastNameDisplay = xml.Element("lastName").Attribute("display").ValueOrDefault("NONE");
```